# Using VS2012 Remote Debugging for developing Surface Apps using Windows 7

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

Is it possible to develop Windows Store apps on a Windows 7 device, by using the Surface RT and VS2012 remote debugging?

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll need a Windows 8 machine for development.